# Is there a way to take parameters from one function and use them in another function?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

There probably isn't an easy way to solve this problem, but I'm willing to try anything.

I am making a button-based rock-paper-scissors game that two people can play on the same computer. I have a function that should accept one input from the first set of buttons and another input from the second set of buttons. However, I am not sure how to get one answer from one button and another answer from another button if they are using separate functions. Is there any way I can do this? I am willing to elaborate my question if it's not that clear.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
  <p id="player1">player 1 turn</p>
    <button onclick="lockInP1(); userInputs('rock')" class="1" id="rock1">Rock</button>
    <button onclick="lockInP1(); userInputs('paper')" class="1" id="paper1">Paper</button>
    <button onclick="lockInP1(); userInputs('scissors')" class="1" id="scissors1">Scissor</button>
    <p>your answer: <span id="choiceP1"></span></p>
  <p id="player2">player 2 turn</p>
    <button onclick="lockInP2(); userInputs(undefined, 'rock')" class="2" id="rock2">Rock</button>
    <button onclick="lockInP2(); userInputs(undefined, 'paper')" class="2" id="paper2">Paper</button>
    <button onclick="lockInP2(); userInputs(undefined, 'scissors')" class="2" id="scissors2">Scissor</button>
    <p>your answer: <span id="choiceP2"></span></p>
    <p id="result">result: </p>
    <a href="index.html"><button>solo mode</button></a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="duel.html"><button>refresh</button></a>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('rock2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('paper2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('scissors2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('player2').hidden = true;
})

function lockInUser(answer){
    document.getElementById('choiceUser').append(answer)
    document.getElementById('rock').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('paper').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('scissors').disabled = true;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    if(random == 0){
        document.getElementById('choiceComp').append('rock');
    } else if(random == 1){
        document.getElementById('choiceComp').append('paper');
    } else if(random == 2){
        document.getElementById('choiceComp').append('scissors');
    } else {
        document.write('integer error, please refresh');
    };
    if(answer == 'rock' && random == 2){
        document.getElementById('result').append('you win');
    } else if(answer == 'paper' && random == 0){
        document.getElementById('result').append('you win');
    } else if(answer == 'scissors' && random == 1){
        document.getElementById('result').append('you win');
    } else if(answer == 'rock' && random == 0){
        document.getElementById('result').append('tie');
    } else if(answer == 'paper' && random == 1){
        document.getElementById('result').append('tie');
    } else if(answer == 'scissors' && random == 2){
        document.getElementById('result').append('tie');
    } else if(answer == 'rock' && random == 1){
        document.getElementById('result').append('you lost');
    } else if(answer == 'paper' && random == 2){
        document.getElementById('result').append('you lost');
    } else if(answer == 'scissors' && random == 0){
        document.getElementById('result').append('you lost');
    }
}


function lockInP1(){
    document.getElementById('choiceP1').append("?????")
    document.getElementById('rock1').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('paper1').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('scissors1').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('player1').hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('rock2').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('paper2').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('scissors2').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('player2').hidden = false;
}

function lockInP2(){
    document.getElementById('choiceP2').append("?????")
    document.getElementById('rock2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('paper2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('scissors2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('player2').hidden = true;
}

function userInputs(answer1, answer2){
    if(answer2){
        if(answer1 == 'rock' && answer2 == 'scissors'){
            document.getElementById('result').append('p1 win');
        } else if(answer1 == 'paper' && answer2 == 'rock'){
            document.getElementById('result').append('p1 win');
        } else if(answer1 == 'scissors' && answer2 == 'paper'){
            document.getElementById('result').append('p1 win');
        } else if(answer1 == 'rock' && answer2 == 'rock'){
            document.getElementById('result').append('tie');
        } else if(answer1 == 'paper' && answer2 == 'paper'){
            document.getElementById('result').append('tie');
        } else if(answer1 == 'scissors' && answer2 == 'scissors'){
            document.getElementById('result').append('tie');
        } else if(answer1 == 'rock' && answer2 == 'paper'){
            document.getElementById('result').append('p2 win');
        } else if(answer1 == 'paper' && answer2 == 'scissors'){
            document.getElementById('result').append('p2 win');
        } else if(answer1 == 'scissors' && answer2 == 'rock'){
            document.getElementById('result').append('p2 win');
        }
    }
    console.log(answer1);
    console.log(answer2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, according to your code your problem is, that you don't track the answers of each player. When player1 presses a button you have answer2 undefined in the call to userInputs and when player2 presses his button you have answer1 undefined.

You can't solve this problem the way you try to do it right now.

First of all there is no synchronicity. It is technically not possible to get both function calls at the same time, even if both players by accident would hit their buttons exactly at the same time, the browser engine checks all the clicks one by one and you will ever get two separate calls with one parameter undefined. Exactly how you wrote it.

So what you need is a way to wait until you know both results and then compare them.

At them moment you're solution is purely based on functions and in fact there also would be a solution with only functions, but it is much easier if you also use variables.

You should add two variables to your script, like

```
let choice1 = null;
let choice2 = null;
```

Next step would be to set that variables with your user clicks.
You can do this with a new function or just use the existing lockInP1 or LockInP2 function. To do so you would need to add a parameter to that functions.

For example your call when player1 clicks rock could start with:

```
<button onclick="lockInP1('rock'); ...
```

In the lockInP1 function you can use the argument to set the variable

```
function lockInP1(userChoice){
  choice1 = userChoice;
  // ... rest of your function code
```

Next thing would be to compare the two answers. Let's now use your userInputs function, but don't call it with hard coded values. Call it always with the variables. In the case of user1 clicks rock, the complete handler would be

```
<button onclick="lockInP1('rock'); userInputs(choice1, choice2)" ...
```

With the lockIn function you have already set one of the variables and by the time you call userInputs either one or both variables will hold a value, which is not 'null'.

Remember that in all of your calls to userInputs the arguments are always the variables choice1 and choice2.

Now the comparison itself takes place in your userInputs function, which will work now like it is. This function is called first when one of the players makes his choice and it doesn't matter which player it is. The variable from the other player will still be null and none of your expressions is true. When the second player makes his choice, the function gets called again, but now both variables will have a value and one of your expressions will match.

You also can get rid of the if-statement checking if there is an answer2, you always pass two arguments, but one may be null.

Last thing, which should not be forgotten is to reset the variables after you have evaluated both answers, so the players can play another round.

Either you can add

```
choice1 = null;
choice2 = null;
```

to all your valid if/else if bodies, where you also append the result to the dom or you can do this at the end of the userInputs function with one conditional checking if both players had made their choice

```
if (answer1 && answer2) {
  choice1 = null;
  choice2 = null;
}
```

One side note: You can also omit the parameters to userInputs completely and just use the variables directly inside the function, but it is a better code style to use parameters and in bigger programs you will see why. In that aspect it would also be better to make a separate function to reset the variables. This is called a setter function and it further helps with data encapsulation and integrity. But I think for your small game you don't need to over engineer it.